# Como manter filtros após paginate e submit

Tags: php, laravel

Criei uma tela de filtros e paginate do laravel.

Os filtros estão todos funcionando, mas eu preciso que após eu ir para a pagina 2, continue os filtros que eu coloquei.

E quando eu coloco os filtros, os  somem.

View:

```
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-12">
            <div class="padding-panel-default">  
                <div class="row">
                    <form action="{!! url('/lms/disciplinas') !!}" method="post">
                        {!! csrf_field() !!}
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                        <label for="nivel_ensino">Nível de Ensino</label>
                        <select name="nivel_ensino" id="nivel_ensino" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Selecione</option>
                            @php
                                $arrNiveis = [];
                            @endphp
                            @foreach ($disciplinas as $disciplina)
                                @if (!in_array($disciplina->nivel, $arrNiveis))
                                    @php
                                        $arrNiveis[] = $disciplina->nivel;
                                    @endphp
                                    <option value="{{$disciplina->nivel}}">{{$disciplina->nivel}}</option>
                                @endif;
                            @endforeach
                            @php
                                unset($arrNiveis);
                            @endphp
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                        <label for="modalidade">Modalidade</label>
                        <select name="modalidade" id="modalidade" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Selecione</option>
                            @php
                                $arrModalidade = [];
                            @endphp
                            @foreach ($disciplinas as $disciplina)
                                @if (!in_array($disciplina->modalidade, $arrModalidade))
                                    @php
                                        $arrModalidade[] = $disciplina->modalidade;
                                    @endphp
                                    <option value="{{$disciplina->modalidade}}">{{$disciplina->modalidade}}</option>
                                @endif;
                            @endforeach
                            @php
                                unset($arrModalidade);
                            @endphp
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                        <label for="periodo">Período</label>
                        <select name="semestre" id="semestre" class="form-control" >
                            <option value="">Selecione</option>
                            @php
                                $arrSemestre = [];
                            @endphp
                            @foreach ($disciplinas as $disciplina)
                                @if (!in_array($disciplina->semestre, $arrSemestre))
                                    @php
                                        $arrSemestre[] = $disciplina->semestre;
                                    @endphp
                                    <option value="{{$disciplina->semestre}}">{{$disciplina->semestre}}</option>
                                @endif;
                            @endforeach
                            @php
                                unset($arrSemestre);
                            @endphp
                        </select>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-3 col-md-2">
                        <label for="periodo">Nome da Disciplina</label>
                        <select name="disciplina" id="disciplina" class="form-control">
                            <option value="">Selecione</option>
                            <?php
                            $arrDisciplinas = [];
                            foreach ($disciplinas as $disciplina) :
                                if (!in_array($disciplina->description, $arrDisciplinas)) :
                                    $arrDisciplinas[] = $disciplina->description; ?>
                            <option value="<?= $disciplina->description; ?>"><?= $disciplina->description; ?></option>
                            <?php endif; endforeach; unset($arrDisciplinas);?>
                        </select>
                    </div>
                        <button>Filtro</button>
                    </form>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="padding-panel-default">

                <div ng-init="disciplinas = {{ json_encode($teste['data'])}}">
                    <div class="row" >
                        <div class="col s12 m6 l4 xl3" ng-repeat="disciplina in disciplinas">
                            <div class="card card-content-admin @{{ disciplina.classDiscipline }} hoverable">
                                <div class="card-content card-content-disciplinas" ng-class="{'tooltipped': disciplina.statusacademico == 'inativa'}">
                                    <p class="card-title truncate">
                                        <div class="valign-wrapper">
                                            <h4 class="text-center">@{{ disciplina.title }}
                                                <br>
                                                <small><b>@{{ disciplina.numerodaturma }}</b></small>
                                                <br>
                                                <small>@{{ disciplina.modalidade }}</small>
                                            </h4>
                                        </div>
                                    </p>
                                </div>
                                <div class="card-action acoes">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col s12 text-center">
                                            @if(\Auth()->user()->roles()->first()->role_type == "student")
                                                <a href="{{URL_STUDENT_LMS_CATEGORIES_VIEW}}@{{ disciplina.slug }}" class="tooltipped" data-position="top" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Acessar as Aulas"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a>
                                                <a href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/@{{ disciplina.drive_folder }}" class="tooltipped" data-position="top" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Acessar o Drive"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i></a>
                                            @else
                                                <a href="{{URL_LMS_AULAS}}@{{ disciplina.slug }}" class="tooltipped" data-position="top" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Acessar as Aulas"><i class="fa fa-external-link"></i></a>
                                                <a href="https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/@{{ disciplina.drive_folder }}" class="tooltipped" data-position="top" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Acessar o Drive" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-folder"></i></a>
                                            @endif
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>



                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php
                if(Auth()->user()->roles()->first()->role_type != "student") {
                ?>
                <div class="fixed-action-btn toolbar hide-on-med-and-up click-to-toggle">
                    <a class="btn-floating btn-large red z-depth-4">
                        <i class="large material-icons">reorder</i>
                    </a>
                    <ul>
                        <li class="tooltipped" data-position="top" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Relatórios"><a href="#" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="tooltipped" data-position="top" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Configuração Composição de Notas"><a href="#" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="tooltipped" data-position="top" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Notificações"><a href="{{URL_NOTIFICACOES_DISCIPLINAS}}" class="btn-floating waves-effect waves-light"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="fixed-action-btn vertical hide-on-small-only click-to-toggle">
                    <a class="btn-floating btn-large red z-depth-4">
                        <i class="large material-icons">reorder</i>
                    </a>
                    <ul class="btn-floating-icon-fa">
                        <li class="tooltipped" data-position="left" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Relatórios"><a href="#" class="btn-floating brown darken-1 waves-effect waves-light"><i class="fa fa-bar-chart"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="tooltipped" data-position="left" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Configuração Composição de Notas"><a href="<?= URL_LMS_NOTAS; ?>" class="btn-floating orange darken-1 waves-effect waves-light"><i class="fa fa-cog"></i></a></li>
                        <li class="tooltipped" data-position="left" data-delay="50" data-tooltip="Notificações"><a href="{{URL_NOTIFICACOES_DISCIPLINAS}}" class="btn-floating blue darken-1 waves-effect waves-light"><i class="fa fa-warning"></i></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <?php } ?>

                {{ $paginate->links() }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Controller:

```
/busca os imputs do filtro
            $semestre = Input::get('semestre');
            $modalidade = Input::get('modalidade');
            $nivel = Input::get('nivel');
            $disciplina = Input::get('disciplina');


    // faz validacao pra ver se é aluno ou professor
    if (Auth()->User()->role->role_type == 'admin' || Auth()->User()->role->role_type == 'owner') {
        $records = LmsDisciplines::select(['lmsdisciplines.*', 'modalidade.name as modalidade', 'nivel.name as nivel'])//aqui busca os filtros
            ->join('modalidade', 'lmsdisciplines.modalidade_id', '=', 'modalidade.id')
            ->join('nivel', 'lmsdisciplines.nivel_id', '=', 'nivel.id')
            ->where([['lmsdisciplines.id', '<>', '1']])
            ->get();

        $disciplina = LmsDisciplines::select(['lmsdisciplines.*', 'modalidade.name as modalidade', 'nivel.name as nivel'])//aqui monta paginate
            ->join('modalidade', 'lmsdisciplines.modalidade_id', '=', 'modalidade.id')
            ->join('nivel', 'lmsdisciplines.nivel_id', '=', 'nivel.id')
            ->where([['lmsdisciplines.id', '<>', '1'],
                ['semestre', 'like', '%'.$semestre.'%'],
                ['modalidade.name', 'like', '%'.$modalidade.'%'],
                ['nivel.name', 'like', '%'.$nivel.'%'],
                ['title', 'like', '%'.$disciplina.'%']])
            ->paginate(24);
    } else {

        $records = LmsDisciplines::disciplineUsers(Auth::user()->id);
    }
```

Comment: Aonde está a sua view de paginação.?

Answer (score 0):

Olá, para facilitar eu sempre utilizei [`appends();`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/pagination#displaying-pagination-results), com o uso do `$request->input();`, isso é, tudo que for enviado no `request` será adicionado na url da paginação, você pode definir na mão cada um, mas fica a seu critério.

No lugar do:

```
{{$disciplina->links() }}
```

Você deve colocar:

```
{{$disciplina->appends($request->input())->links() }}
```

> Essa paginação deve ser inserida na blade, como de costume.